Отсутствует перевод для информации про предлагаемые правки
У меня ещё нет 2k репутации, поэтому я могу только предлагать правки.
Нет перевода для "Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed" (когда я редактирую вопрос или ответ):




Перевод добавлен. https://ru.traducir.win/strings/20966
Будет на сайте в следующих сборках. Текущая  2024.11.26.19325
Хочу напомнить, что переводы через https://ru.traducir.win можно предлагать самостоятельно и уже приходить на Мету с готовой ссылкой для утверждения. Можно даже в виде самоответа.

Понял. ​
